# code flow misunderstanding?

Tags: javascript, json

after [looking](http://www.json.org/) at JSON syntax ( just for curiosity)

ive noticed a different `flow tags edges` :

so what is the difference between :

[image]

vs

[image]

Comment: It's an interesting question, but given what we know about the syntax there's no apparent difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe difference comes from lexical analysis, i.e. number and string are lexical "tokens" while value and array are grammar entities (productions).

Comment: This is probably right, although with a syntax diagram of that form the distinction is kind-of thin.

Comment: @Pointy ive been searching about it  , it is called '_ railroad diagrams_'

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes, I remember them from a really long time ago when there was a popular poster available for Pascal syntax :-)  I haven't found any reference for this particular representation, however.

Comment: me too. didnt find the explanation for this syntax. ( searched till now...). p.s. what is the picture from your profile pic ?

Answer (score 2):

You can see that `value` is made up of a number of possible entities, including entities that are defined elsewhere on the page.

`string` on the other hand contains no entities that are defined elsewhere on the page; you can think of it as being made up of some fundamental or primitive entities.

In this way, `string` and `number` are terminal entities that are broken down no further; the double bars indicate this.